# How to issue "subscribe" command after entered the "pub/sub" mode?

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

I can't find any way to subscribe other channels after entered the "pub/sub" mode when using the redis-cli. For example:

```
$ redis-cli
redis> SUBSCRIBE channel:1
Reading messages... (press Ctrl-C to quit)
1) "subscribe"
2) "channel:1"
3) (integer) 1
```

When I press Ctrl-C, the redis-cli is quit instead of "pub/sub" mode. Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't issue new commands in redis-cli after subscribing to a channel. However, the [SUBSCRIBE](http://redis.io/commands/subscribe) command is variadic since version 2.4, meaning you can pass several channels at once, to subscribe to:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> SUBSCRIBE channel:1 channel:2
Reading messages... (press Ctrl-C to quit)
1) "subscribe"
2) "channel:1"
3) (integer) 1
1) "subscribe"
2) "channel:2"
3) (integer) 2
```

Comment: What if I want to UNSUBSCRIBE a channel after SUBSCRIBE command in the redis-cli?

Answer (score 3):

Actually,  [SUBSCRIBE](http://redis.io/commands/subscribe) and [PSUBSCRIBE](http://redis.io/commands/psubscribe) will both block all subsequent commands, thus you can't ship any order to the server but cast your eager gaze back to wait your interested channel for the incoming message. Well, This ridiculous behavior makes my head spin also.
However, if you try to access redis by means of  telnet `telnet localhost 6379` instead of redis-cli. Everything will be OK. check it out plz.

Comment: -ERR only (P)SUBSCRIBE / (P)UNSUBSCRIBE / QUIT allowed in this context

Answer (score 0):

It is *the problem of `redis-cli`, not Redis*.

Redis says that we are **allowed** to issue `SUBSCRIBE`s after issuing one `SUBSCRIBE`. However, the `redis-cli` will **block** everything.

Thus, as suggested by @user1611552, we can use

```
telnet localhost 6379
```

instead of `redis-cli`, and everything would be fine.